# Dispatching Rust TcpStream from TcpListener to separate method in loop

Tags: rust, traits, tcplistener

I'm new to Rust and have the following code:

```rust
while let Some(tcp_stream) = incoming.next() {
    match tcp_stream {
        Ok(s) => {
            handle_request(tcp_stream.unwrap(), &routes);
        }
        Err(ref e) if e.kind() == io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock => {
            continue;
        }
        Err(e) => panic!("Error"),
    };
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
use of moved value: `tcp_stream`

value used here after partial move

note: move occurs because value has type `std::net::TcpStream`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait rustc(E0382)
lib.rs(72, 20): value moved here
lib.rs(73, 36): value used here after partial move
```

What I'm looking to do is handle the new connection/TcpStream in a separate method `handle_request` but I'm unsure how to go about doing this. Passing a reference gives the same issue. I tried implementing the `Copy` trait for `TcpStream` but since I'm outside of its crate I can't seem to do that.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Heya, have you read the [error handling chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html)? I'm not sure how much you need explained in the answer... Simply, `match` statements consume the values you match over, and you want to use the `s: TcpStream` you've extracted from the `Result`.

Comment: Tried using tcp_stream.try_clone() ?

Comment: Oh of course, makes sense, thanks @Plecra! I'll give the chapter a read too.

Answer (score 1):

One fix is to perform error checking in one arm:

```rust
async fn listen(self, listener: TcpListener) {
    let routes = self.routes;
    let mut incoming = listener.incoming();
    while let Some(tcp_stream) = incoming.next() {
        match tcp_stream {
            Ok(s) => {
                handle_request(tcp_stream.unwrap(), &routes);
            }
            Err(e) => {
                if e.kind() == io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock {
                    continue;
                }
                panic!("Error");
            },
        };
    }
}
```